# How to stop follow sidebar when it reach to footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onscroll

I have sidebar that following by scrolling.
If the sidebar reach down to footer, how to stop to follow?

This is what I tried so far here.

```js
$(function() {
  var floatPosition = parseInt($("#left_menu").css('top'));

  $(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var newPosition = scrollTop + floatPosition + "px";
    var newPosition2 = scrollTop;

    $("#left_menu").stop().animate({
      "top" : newPosition2
    }, 400);

  }).scroll();
});
```

```css
.left_menu{position:absolute;top:0;left:0;width:100px; height:330px; margin-top: 30px; background:green}
#footer { background:gray; height:100px;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left_menu" class="left_menu">menu</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="footer">foot</div>
```

Please help

Comment: You already opened this question a few days ago. Where is the old one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check if bottom position of `#left_menu` is greater than top position of `#footer`, prevent increasing it. Note that you should remove CSS `margin-top` of `#left_menu`

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height = $("#left_menu").height();
  var top = $("#footer").offset().top;

  if (scrollTop+height > top)
    scrollTop = top-height;

  $("#left_menu").stop().animate({
    "top": scrollTop
  }, 400);
}).scroll();
```

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
  var height = $("#left_menu").height();
  var top = $("#footer").offset().top;
    
  if (scrollTop+height > top)
    scrollTop = top-height;
  
  $("#left_menu").stop().animate({
    "top": scrollTop
  }, 400);
}).scroll();
```

```css
.left_menu{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100px; 
  height:330px; 
  background:green
}
#footer { 
  background:gray; 
  height:100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="left_menu" class="left_menu">menu</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<div id="footer">foot</div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
```